# React: Creating a row per item in an array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am passing an array of objects as a prop to my Table component, it is supposed to turn every item in the array to a row in a table. But it is not outputting anything...

I have used `console.log` to successfully look into each item within the array. This is my code:

```
import React from 'react'; 

export default class Table extends React.Component {
    getTableRow(x) {
        console.log(x); 
        return ( <tr>
                <td>{x.prop1}</td>
                <td>{x.prop2}</td>
                <td>{x.prop3}</td>
        </tr>); 
    }

    resolveInput() {
        //expecting array
        const array = this.props.lastFiveList; 
        //array.map(x => console.log(x)); 
        array.map(x => this.getTableRow(x)); 
    }           

    render() {
        return (
            <table>
             {this.resolveInput()}
            </table>
        ); 
    }
}
```

I have also tried to bind both functions (same result) and place what `getTableRow` is supposed to return into a variable and then returned the variable instead of the multiline `return();` statement. Furthermore, I tried using `forEach` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning the array in `resolveInput()`:

```
    return array.map(x => this.getTableRow(x));
```

Comment: I'd need more info on the component to help you. Where does `this.props.lastFiveList` come from?

Comment: Nevermind, I resolved it. You were right... My resolveInput was not returning anything. Thank you, Miguel! I think your response came in first, so consider your answer the accepted answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @user8951490 Note also that you'll get warnings about `tr`s not being a child of a `tbody` element, and your `tr`s need keys. [Here's a fixed version](https://jsfiddle.net/p9pqfm0t/8/).

Answer (score 3):

`resolveInput` method is not returning anything. You need to return

```
resolveInput() {
    //expecting array
    const array = this.props.lastFiveList; 
    //array.map(x => console.log(x)); 
    return  array.map(x => this.getTableRow(x)); 


}
```

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli thanks for pointing. I updated the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You resolveInput() method is not returning the array that you have created from the map or returning anything for that matter.
So try return the new array that you mapped from the array that was passed in.